# What I am getting NullPointerExcpetion for Uri when inserting values

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
val displayName = "Image-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
val imageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
val imageFile = File(imageDir, displayName)
val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos)
fos.flush()
fos.close()

val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES}/")
}

val resolver = requireContext().contentResolver
val uri = resolver?.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
```

I am trying to get Uri of the inserted image in my Fragment but somehow it is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Can you add stack trace ? it will help us to figure it out where it is having issue

Comment: Add some stackstrace flr the errors you are getting!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using FileProvider to get the Uri as following:

```kotlin
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "${context?.packageName}.fileprovider", file2)
```

And then adding provider in manifest.